# Secure android communication with a server

Tags: android, sockets, client-server

I am very new to writing apps so please bear with me!

I am writing an app that needs to communicate securely with a java server (under my control).

Firstly to login to the server, and then send data back and forth. What is the best way of doing this?

My first thoughts was to communicate to a webpage via ssl with the username and password. e.g. login.php with user=xxx and pass=zzz as posted variable. The site returns a random string and saves it in the database.

If the user then stays logged in, this string is saved on the app. This is then sent with every communication. e.g. set_temp.php with string=123456 and temp=20

This seemed easiest to complete, and I have done most of this.

Alternatively, my other thoughts was to go through a sockets approach and commumicate with the Java server directly. Would this be more secure? Is this even possible?

Or are there any other suggestions? How do the big apps like facebook and gmail secure data?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a webservice on your java machine to communicate with. All requests are via HTTPS and you can login the user via the webservice. Also I would add a time limit to the users loggedin session to ensure that he is logged out properly after some time limit.

Comment: Thanks, that has confirmed what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Use SSL protocol. You can create API services on the server and communicate with them. To keep the user logged in use SessionID. Take a look at DefaultHttpClient() class.

I hope this is useful :)

Comment: Thanks, but Tobiask just beat you too it. :-)

Comment: for nothing :) I am not fighting with anyone. I am just trying to help you :)